# Titanium Studio not Launching iphone app

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

hi im developing iphone application in titanium studio i have mac intel machine with mac os x  10.5.8 with iphone sdk 3.1.3 installed ,

i am facing a problem i have successfully install titanium studio when i creat new project there is an option enable for iphone i checked it and it create a project but when i try to run this project in run as there i no option enabled and it is not launching project kindly someone adice what im doing wrong to configure iphone project,any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please continue on this question. Either accept the answer, or go in-depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements are listed on the website:

> 1. Requirements
>
>    Intel-based computer with Mac OS X (10.6)
>
> Necessary for Installing on Device:
>
> ```
> An Apple iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)
> iOS developer certification
> ```

Your OSX version is not compatible!

http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started